# Replace "*" with "-" in given character array

Tags: java

> Given character array is

`char[] arr = {123*4*5}`

> output should be

`String str = "123-4-5"`

Comment: You might have better luck with `char[] arr = {'1','2','3','*','4','*','5'};` - your current "array" contains a single value, and there isn't a good way to reverse the multiplication.

Comment: Do you want to convert your char array to String object as well? Or just a simple replace

Comment: @ElliottFrisch there is no way to change the array format, It's interview question. no matters how many values are there you need to parse it and replace those * character with -

Comment: @smac89 try using any IDE , then you will get to know

Comment: @stark9190 I want to replace those * character with -, that's it.

Comment: @smac89 A java char is a 16-bit integral type. You can store the value, but you can't reverse the operation.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, you're right

Comment: You will need some compile time magic to replace that expression with what you are asking for. The value of your expression cannot be reversed because there are an infinite number of things that can evaluate to the same value

Comment: `char[] arr = {123*4*5}` is `char[] arr = {2460};` - now you need to find a way to turn 2460 into `123-4-5`. Best of luck!

Comment: @gurioso Agreed, though they might actually screw up interview questions on purpose to see how you handle it. Simulating RL (real life), where requirements are messed up, and you have to figure out what the actual requirements are, before you can implement it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have posted an answer than does just that. I would be glad if you could provide feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) That's not how you declare a char array. As pointed in comments it should be:

```
char[] arr = {'1','2','3','*','4','*','5'};
```

2) If you want a `String` why don't you start with a `String`?

3) You could construct a `String` from a `char[]` and use `String.replace(char oldchar, char new char)` which comes as the first result in a Google search. Code:

```
char[] arr = {'1','2','3','*','4','*','5'};
String str = String.valueOf(arr).replace('*', '-');
```

4) If you need to do it on a `char[]` before a `String` is made, you could simply loop through the array:

```
char[] arr = {'1','2','3','*','4','*','5'};
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    if(arr[i] =='*') arr[i] = '-';
String str = String.valueOf(arr);
```

---

EDIT: based on the comments and discussion with OP, the question seems to be exactly as posted. That is:

```
char[] arr = {xxx*y*z};
String str = transformCharArr(arr);
```

For `arr={123*4*5}`: `str = "123-4-5"` and for `arr={122*2}`: `str = "122-2"`.

Therefore, I made a small function that achieves just that and solves both cases.

Assumptions:

1) xxx is always a three digit number, minimum is 100, maximum is 999.

2) y is non-zero 1 digit number [1-9], same with z.

3) In case y or z is equal to 1, it's ignored given multiplication by 1 changes nothing to the outcome.

4) xxx is always minimized. That is, for `123*4*5`, the lowest possible `xxx` to achieve this is 123 with respect to assumption (1) that xxx>=100.

5) y and z are maximized with z being favored for maximization. Also with respect to assumption (2) for both.

Therefore, code is:

```
static String transformCharArr(char[] arr){
    if(arr.length > 1) return ""; // array should only contain 1 element
    int value = (int)arr[0]; // using int since char is the only unisgned 2-byte type in all of Java, short isn't enough given MAX(short) = 32,767 while max(char) = 65,535
    short xxx=100, y=1, z=1; // all shorts since they never exceed certain limits
    int product = 0; // to stop the loop, int because short*short*short gives int type, and product is comparable to value, so it has to support more than max(short)
    for(xxx=100; xxx<=999; xxx++){ // first loop xxx to minimize it
        for(y=1; y<=9; y++){ // loop y before z to favor maximizing z
            for(z=1; z<=9; z++){ // ensures maximizing z before y
                if((product = xxx*y*z)== value) 
                    break;
            }
            if(product == value) break;
        }
        if(product == value) break;
    }
    if(y==1) return String.format("%d-%d", xxx, z); // if y is 1, ignore it
    if(z==1) return String.format("%d-%d", xxx, y); // if z is 1 ignore it
    return String.format("%d-%d-%d", xxx,y,z);
}
```

Testing it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] arr1 = {123*4*5};
    System.out.println(transformCharArr(arr1));
    char[] arr2 = {122*2};
    System.out.println(transformCharArr(arr2));
}
```

Output:

```
123-4-5
122-2
```

Analysis:

Time-complexity: O(C) given the loop cannot run more than `999*9*9` and it is ALWAYS guaranteed to find `value` before `xxx=9 y=9 z=9` given that `999*9*9 = ‭80,919‬ > max(char)=65,535`

Comment: the answer you are provided is not expected on. If it's simple char array then everyone can solve this problem easily. Actually it's a tricky way to declare a character array

Comment: @RajuMuke I see what you are trying to do. With no extra information, it's impossible to determine how to do it. You have a character (A SINGLE CHARACTER) that you wish to decompose into 3 numbers which are multiplied together, and then generate a string out of this multiplication where you replace the multiplication symbol with a dash. the number `2460` can be `1230*2`, or `615*4` or `615*2*2` or (as in question) `123*4*5`. How on earth are you supposed to decompose it into `123*4*5` out of all the infinite possibilities with no extra info?

Comment: nah, its a finite number of possibilites, one fits. but then, why not generate just all permutations of length 6 with "-" and a number?

Comment: @Everyone I think we are human , for us everything is possible . It's seems to impossible until someone do it.

Comment: @gurioso the point is: it's impossible to "randomly" pick the one permutation that was used in the declaration of the "array." unless you have access to the Java source code file where you read the file and know, beforehand, where the line of declaration is. If you can do that then you might as well take it as a substring and use it without going through that hassle.

Comment: @RajuMuke you gave no information regarding how to pick it. Here is the thing: all permutations of multiplying 3 integers to generate a larger integer are 100% equal. If you want to limit the permutations to only one, you need to set certain rules to do so. Your question provided no such rules. As long as you don't know the rules, no one knows the answer. So now tell me, are you asking us how to set such rules?

Comment: @RajuMuke would you be so kind to provide other test cases and their expected outputs? I may actually give you a solution to this problem, but with more test cases I would be more confident in it. That is, I am setting the "rules" to pick the permutation.

Comment: @Everyone here is new test case char[ ] arr={122*2} , expected output should be string str= "122-2". I believe this is simpler test case as compared to previous one

Comment: @RajuMuke thanks, is there a case where the outcome is a two-digit number? or a case where the outcome is a 5 digit number? So far we have a test case for a product result of 2560 (4 digits), and 244 (3 digits). If you could provide more test cases, we can derive the relationship between them and figure out the algorithm to solve it.

Comment: @AndyTurner I am well aware. My original edit had that, but since Java hates `==` for non-primitive types, I decided to go with this.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know it's just to use Java's method of doing it. I prefer `==` but some may prefer `compare`.

Comment: @AndyTurner very well, changed back :p

Comment: @RajuMuke there you go. Unless you provide more test cases, the method above does exactly what you asked.

Comment: Could it not be `arr = {1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1};`? Replace any one one with any other term.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks for feedback. The provided test cases (2 so far) have not shown such case. So I assumed it wasn't. It is difficult when little data is provided.

Comment: @Everyone char[] arr={123*25*3}; this testcase is getting failed. I think you just consider only those two test cases only .you need to try with negative test cases as well. char[] arr={123*25}; this test is also failed. Think some generic solution which works for all test cases.

Comment: @RajuMuke that is why I asked for all test cases but you don't seem to provide them. Can you list all of them in your question?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should know is that the `123 * 4 * 5` means 2460,so the point by upstairs is right.which like this :

```java
char[] arr = {'1','2','3','*','4','*','5'};
System.out.println(new String(arr).replaceAll("\\*","-"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] arr = {'1','2','3','*','4','*','5'};
String str = String.valueOf(arr).replace('*', '-');
```

get a string from your char arrays and take the replace method to repalce '*' from '-'